# SQL - How to select distinct and join multiple tables without duplicating data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following table setup/data:

```
create table #temp (irecordid int, sdocumentno varchar(20), dtfileddate datetime, mnyconsideration money)

insert into #temp values (1, '3731572', '6-30-2014', 120.00)

Create table #temp2 (irecordid int, address varchar(255))

insert into #temp2 values (1, '406 N CUSTER')
insert into #temp2 values (1, '2015 E HANSON')


Create table #temp3 (irecordid int, srdocumentno varchar(25))
insert into #temp3 values (1, '55489')
insert into #temp3 values (1, '99809')
```

I am trying to select so I only get a distinct instance of each table.  I am trying:

```
select distinct sdocumentno, address, srdocumentno
from #temp t1
join #temp2 t2 on t1.irecordid = t2.irecordid
join #temp3 t3 on t1.irecordid = t3.irecordid
```

And my results are as follows:

```
3731572 2015 E HANSON   55489
3731572 2015 E HANSON   99809
3731572 406 N CUSTER    55489
3731572 406 N CUSTER    99809
```

I would really like only the distinct data from each table like this:

```
3731572   2015 E HANSON   55489
3731572   406 N CUSTER   99809
```

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: Which of the two records woud you like to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you want to `join` on "row number", but that doesn't exist.  But, you can generate one and then join on them:

```
select sdocumentno, address, srdocumentno
from #temp t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by irecordid order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from #temp2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.irecordid = t2.irecordid join
     (select t3.*,
             row_number() over (partition by irecordid order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from #temp2 t3
     ) t3
     on t1.irecordid = t3.irecordid and t2.seqnum = t3.seqnum;
```

You can use `full outer join` if the lists are of different lengths.